# Selecting values where one value is the same, but another is different

Tags: sql, select, unique, advantage-database-server

Using Advantage SQL, and if I have column a, which is an identifier for a learner, column b is the specific aim they're studying, and column c is an end date where applicable, I only want to see the ident and the latest end date of that ident ONLY if all of the aims belonging to that ident have an end date.
I have tried:

```
select ident
into #tmp
from pclscvq
where fundend is not null
group by ident
```

The problem with the above is that it brings through idents that have some, but not all with end dates.

I've attached the results for one query, showing the three columns. The example is what I don't want to see, but I get using the code I provided above. What I want, based on this results is only to see the ident (column a), where fundend (column c), has a date entered against all related aims (vq_ref-column b)

[image: Myscreenshot]

Any ideas?

Comment: You should try to add sample data and expected results, it is pretty hard to understand exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

By using a `where not exists`, yuo can exclude all the idents with a null end date in any aim

```
select distinct ident
from pclscvq t1
where not exists (select 1 
                  from pclscvq t2 
                  where t2.ident = t1.ident 
                  and t2.fundend  is null)
```

If your DBMS does not support this, you can self join:

```
select distinct ident
from  pclscvq t1
left join pclscvq t2
on t1.ident = t2.ident
and t2.fundend is null
where t1.ident is not null
and t1.fundend is not null
```

or use a `not in` (last resort)

```
select distinct ident
from  pclscvq t1
where ident not in (select ident from pclscvq where fundend is null)
```